# How to read media files(audio files , not text files ) in a jar file ?

Tags: java, audio, jar, wav

```
    Media.jar
    |--gmor.wav
    +--some.txt
```

the code below can not work to get the inputstream , and throws 
java.lang.NullPointerException .
     input   = JarFileRead.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some.txt");  can work.

[code]

```
import java.io.*;
public class JarFileRead
{
public static InputStream input = null;
public JarFileRead()
   {
       try
       {
           input = JarFileRead.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("gmor.wav");

           while(input.read()!=-1)
           {

               System.out.print(input.read());
           }
           input.close();
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
public static void main(String [] args)
{
   new JarFileRead();
}
```

}

[/code]

Comment: Note that JavaSound has been known to choke on 'non-repositionable' input streams.  The stream returned from `getResourceAsStream` is apparently such a stream.  Use `getResource()` to get an `URL` instead.  But implement the fixes identified by Stephen C 1st, that is the immediate problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `getResourceAsStream` method returns `null` if it can't find the resource that you asked for.  Your code doesn't check for the `null`, and that is the cause of your NPEs.

So the solution is:

- Check that the file actually exists in the JAR, in the location that it is supposed to exist.
- Change the pathname to be correct for the way that you are using that method.

---

Note: if you were trying to name the file relative to `JarFileRead`, then you need to do this:

```
JarFileRead.class.getResourceAsStream("gmor.wav");
```

The way you are currently doing it should resolve relative paths relative to the root of the namespace; i.e. it is equivalent to asking for `"/gmor.wav"`.  But it that is what you mean, it is simpler and clearer to write:

```
JarFileRead.class.getResourceAsStream("/gmor.wav");
```